# Visual Studio 2017 - Configure minimum character count that triggers autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Autocomplete suggestions in Visual Studio 2017 appear after typing only 1 character. For example if you type the letter 'i' a window instantly appears with the list of variables and keywords that start with that character. This becomes quite annoying if you have single letter variables like 'i', 'j', 'a', 'b', etc.

- Is there a way to make the suggestions appear after not 1, but 3 (or any other number) of characters typed?

I have searched the options but with no luck and whatever I type in Google doesn't seem to give me what i need. For reference, Notepad++ has this option in "Preferences -> Auto-Completion -> Enable auto-completion on each input -> from n-th character"

Comment: If you've looked at all the available options, and this was not one of them, then I guess you have your answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

Perhaps this is a timely reminder that you should minimise your use of such non-descriptive variable names. Since you have auto-complete, it's not even a typing chore to use more letters.